# What is the use of provider in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider

Well, I am sort of new to Flutter, My question is why we use providers in Flutter, I know it is used for state management. But I am looking to know the most common use case of providers.

Answer (score 4):

You need to be able to move data between your Widgets. It's an easy way to do it.

You start your root Build method in the app with:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(  // Multi means you can have more providers if you need
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (context) => MyStateClass()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(....
```

Now you can place all the data you need to share in the `MyStateClass()` and place underlying Widgets inside:

```
   Consumer<MyStateClass>(builder: (context, state, child) {

      // your code here - return(SomeOtherWidget());
    })
```

or inside your Build methods:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   MyStateClass state = Provider.of<MyStateClass>(context);
   // ... TODO  ... return (Widget)
```

Answer (score 4):

As you asked that why we use **provider** in flutter, so i will be providing only theoretical explanation which i think will surely help you to understand what 
actually provider is and why it is used.

Suppose you are working on a large app with a lot of folders and files.
Now if the user have interacted with your app(say pressed a button or something like that) then the app have to build itself again to update to the changes that the user had made.But wait! this doesn't looks a good deal, to build the whole app again just to make changes in some particular section.

So, here comes the **Provider** to solve this problem.

A **Provider** is basically a container or a storage that stores and provides you with state or data.
Also, we know that widgets are arranged in an app like a tree like fashion.
so, if u assign Provider to any node in the tree then all the children of that node will have access to the data that is provided by the **Provider**.

Back the stage ,**Provider** comes with a **listener** and these **listeners** are assigned to the children of the widget to which **Provider** is attached.

So, **If the user interferes with any widget that has a listener** then the app will build only that particular (which the user interacted) widget again (not the whole app).

Answer (score 3):

**What is provider and how it's works ?**

Provider is a simple way for state management, it works on the concept of PUB_SUB,

Which means there is one provider and multiple subscribers which is called consumers here. ex : youtube.

Whenever there is change, with NotifyChangeListener it will update all the consumers.

Answer (score 0):

A wrapper around InheritedWidget to make them easier to use and more reusable.

By using provider instead of manually writing InheritedWidget, you get:

- simplified allocation/disposal of resources lazy
- loading a vastly reduced boilerplate over making a new class every
  time devtools friendly
- using Provider, the state of your application will be visible in the Flutter devtools a common way to consume these InheritedWidgets